# Zend_Form_Element_Captcha display image only with digits

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, captcha, zend-form-element

I'm using Zend_Form_Element_Captcha like this:

```
         $this->view->captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
            'label' => 'Codice di controllo:',
            'required' => true,
            'captcha' => array(
                'captcha' => 'Image',
                'font' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/default/fonts/arial.ttf',
                'fontSize' => '22',
                'wordLen' => 6,
                'height' => '57',
                'width' => '135',
                'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/captcha',
                'imgUrl' => Zend_Registry::get('URL') . 'public/images/captcha',
                )
            ));
```

And i need my captcha image to display only small letters, not capital letters. Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: Zend does not provide an option for limit char set. Use a font with contain only the numbers.

Comment: Only digits or only small letters? :)

Comment: I think the font idea is a good one. Thanks

Comment: @Asuraya, Setting a font file than only contains a few range of caracters will result validation failures!!!
Imagine that the word is generated is `de8db2`, the word will be drawn, for example,  like `dehdbz`. The user will enter `dehdbz` but the validator is expecting `de8db2`! The user will be fir sure in conflict!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want digits, you can try this:

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha(...);

$capcha_addapter = $captcha->getCaptcha();
$capcha_addapter->setUseNumbers(false); // No digit
$captcha->setCaptcha($capcha_addapter);

$this->view->captcha = $captcha;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use numbers, simply use the `useNumbers` option

```
$this->view->captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
    'label' => 'Codice di controllo:',
    'required' => true,
    'captcha' => array(
        'captcha'     => 'Image',
        'useNumbers'  => false,
        'font'        => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/default/fonts/arial.ttf',
        'fontSize'    => '22',
        'wordLen'     => 6,
        'height'      => '57',
        'width'       => '135',
        'imgDir'      => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/captcha',
        'imgUrl'      => Zend_Registry::get('URL') . 'public/images/captcha',
        )
    ));
```

As a general solution to setting the char list to be used in generating Captcha would be extending the `Zend_Captcha_Image` class and override the `_generateWord` protected method.

Hope it helps

Comment: @Downvoter, please consider leaving a comment to help me improve my answer (or future answers)